# Find sum of calls data from array using another array of dates

Tags: php

```
$array1 = Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2014-05-07
            [total_Calls] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2014-05-09
            [total_Calls] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2014-05-12
            [total_Calls] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2014-05-13
            [total_Calls] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2014-05-14
            [total_Calls] => 2
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2014-05-16
            [total_Calls] => 4
        )

);


$array2 = Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [report_date] => 1397413800-1397932200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [report_date] => 1398018600-1398537000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [report_date] => 1398623400-1399141800
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [report_date] => 1399228200-1399746600
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [report_date] => 1399833000-1400351400
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [report_date] => 1400437800-1400956200
        )

)
```

I want to find sum of total_Calls between dates that is in second array. I need out put like this.

I have got output using for loop but i dont want to use for loop

```
 $array = array();
     foreach ($array1 as $val) {
         $temp = str_replace('-', '', $val['day']);
         $array[strtotime($temp)] = $val['total_Calls'];
     }
      $week = array();

     $sum = array();
     foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
         foreach ($array2 as $val) {
             $temp = explode('-', $val['report_date']);
             if ($k >= $temp[0] && $k <= $temp[1]) {
                 $sum[$val['report_date']][] = $v;
             } else {
                 $sum[$val['report_date']][] = 0;
             }
         }
     }
```

Output:

```
     [1397413800-1397932200] => 0
     [1398018600-1398537000] => 0
     [1398623400-1399141800] => 0
     [1399228200-1399746600] => 2
     [1399833000-1400351400] => 9
     [1400437800-1400956200] => 8
```

Comment: `I need out put like this`. So what have you done for that.?

Comment: I have done using for loop like this one but i dont want using for loop

Comment: Don't post code as comment. Instead of that edit your question and update the code

Comment: edited question and put my code that i have used for output. make it +ve.

Comment: Your current code is NOT giving you that output

Answer (score 0):

BRUTEFORCE!!!

```
<?php
$from_to = array();
foreach ($array2 as $data) {
    $days = explode('-', $data['report_date']);
    $from_to[] = $days;
}

$counter = array();
foreach ($array1 as $data) {
    $day = new Datetime($data['day'], new Datetimezone('UTC'));
    $timestamp = $day->('U');
    foreach ($from_to as $range) {
        if ($timestamp >= $range[0] && $timestamp <= $range[1]) {
            $key = implode('-', $range);
            if (!isset($counter[$key])) {
                $counter[$key] = 0;
            }

            $counter[$key] += $data['total_Calls'];
        }
    }
}

print_r($counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in trying to avoid using loops. In fact, however you do it, you will be using loops. Either by writing one, or by using some native or custom function that will eventually use one. As that is just the way you walk through an array.

What you might want to do however is try to have as little loops as possible. And do the heavy work, such as `strtotime()` outside (most of) the loops, where possible.

I've given your code a walk over and compacted it. You will have your results inside `$new_array`.

```
foreach($array1 as $key=>$value)
    $array1[$key]["timestamp"] = strtotime($array1[$key]["day"]);
foreach($array2 as $report) {
    $new_array[$report["report_date"]] = 0;
    $from_to = array_map("intval",explode("-",$report["report_date"]));
    foreach($array1 as $call_day) {
        $day = $call_day["timestamp"];
        if ($day >= $from_to[0] &&  $day < $from_to[1])
            $new_array[$report["report_date"]] += $call_day["total_Calls"];
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/E9hviy)